# How to determine if property exists using SinonJS?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I've been searching around and can't find a simple sinon example (assertion?) checking that function `.doSomething` exists.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var myModule = require('my-module');

describe('myModule', function () {
  it('has a function .doSomething', function () {
    // check whether typeof myModule.doSomething === 'function'
  });
});
```

What is the correct way to check if this function exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sinon.assert.match(myModule.doSomething, sinon.match.func);
```

or

```
sinon.assert.match(typeof myModule.doSomething, "function");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be done with an assertion library, not sinon (which is a stub/mock library).

[Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/) is a popular option for use with mocha:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var myModule = require('my-module');

describe('myModule', function () {
  it('has a function .doSomething', function () {
    expect(myModule.doSomething).to.be.a('function')
  });
});
```